# bootstrap datepicker today as default

Tags: javascript, html, date, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using this [bootstrap-datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) for my datepicker. I'd like the datepicker to choose "today" for start day or default day. 
I cannot figure out how to set "today" automatically, so I did an inefficient way

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value ="today();" id="datepicker"/>
```

JS:

```
 $('#datepicker').datepicker();
function today(){
    var d = new Date();
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1;
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    document.write(curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year);
}
```

Online Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/BXZk2/

Just looking for an easy solution to make the default day as "TODAY".

Thanks

Answer (score 96, accepted):

This should work:

`$("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date());`

And for autoclose ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/her2p/)):

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
        "setDate": new Date(),
        "autoclose": true
});
```

[jQuery > datepicker API](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate)

Comment: So this way is not working? `$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  autoclose: true,
  setDate: new Date()
 });`

Comment: Doesn't look like `autoclose` is a valid option, that may be why.

Comment: but it works this way `$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  autoclose: true,
  
 });
`

Comment: I currently have two blocks `$("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date());` and


 `$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  autoclose: true,
 
 });` this way works

Comment: Check the update, that worked for me (autoclose is a bootstrap-specific function apparently)

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, that one doesnt work as the default date is empty. this one works the same as what I am having now. Separate blocks  http://jsfiddle.net/aekjD/

Comment: This answer is invalid actually, because it talk about `jquery datepicker` and the question is about `bootstrap datepicker`

Answer (score 49):

Set after Init

```
 $('#dp-ex-3').datepicker({ autoclose: true, language: 'es' });
$('#dp-ex-3').datepicker('update', new Date());
```

This example is working.

Comment: Thanks! This is the only solution that works for the Bootstrap DatePicker plugin. You first instantiate a datepicker, then set the date on it.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 35):

I used this code

```
$('#datePicker').datepicker({
                    format:'mm/dd/yyyy',
                }).datepicker("setDate",'now');
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the only way that works for me. jQuery UI - v1.12.1 - 2021-06-06,  jQuery dependency v3.3.1 and I can NOT get those above work

Comment: up-voted. this is the only one that works for me (from above, not tried below answers) using bootstrap-datepicker as per question.
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js

Answer (score 16):

Date picker with current date and basic settings:

```
// Datepicker
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    immediateUpdates: true,
    todayBtn: true,
    todayHighlight: true
}).datepicker("setDate", "0");
```

Comment: Set as 3 days before:   $('.datepicker'){.....}).datepicker("setDate", "-3");

Answer (score 12):

If none of the above option work, use the following :

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker();
$(".datepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

### It works fine for me...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var today = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());

    $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        orientation: 'bottom'
    });

    $('#datepicker1').datepicker('setDate', today);

});
```

Answer (score 7):

I used this a little example and it worked.

```
$('#date').datetimepicker({
    defaultDate: new Date()
});
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/m2fjw57b/1/

Comment: You're using another plugin in your fiddle: bootstrap-datetimepicker. The one in question here is bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: @olefrank is right but It works for bootstrap-datetimepicker and worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

For bootstrap date picker

```
$( ".classNmae" ).datepicker( "setDate", new Date());
```

* new Date is jquery default function in which you can pass custom date & if it not set, it will take current date by default

Answer (score 5):

This question is about bootstrap date picker. But all of the above answers are for the jquery date picker.
For Bootstrap datepicker, you just need to provide the defaut date in the value of the input element. Like this.

```
<input class="form-control datepicker" value=" <?= date("Y-m-d") ?>">
```

Answer (score 3):

It's simple

```
$(function() {
    $("#datePicker").datetimepicker({
        defaultDate:'now'       
    });
});
```

This will be set today as the default

Comment: this's working for "datetimepicker" plugin not for "datepicker".

Answer (score 3):

Simply put the following one. This works for me.

```
$('.className').datepicker('setDate', 'now');
```

Answer (score 2):

According to this link [Set default date of jquery datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646590/jquery-datepicker-default-date), the other solution is

```
var d = new Date();

var currDate = d.getDate();
var currMonth = d.getMonth();
var currYear = d.getFullYear();

var dateStr = currDate + "-" + currMonth + "-" + currYear;

$("#datepicker").datepicker(({dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" autoclose: true, defaultDate: dateStr });
```

Comment: this question is about the bootstrap datepicker, which is similar, but uses a different set of options than the jquery UI datepicker. see https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html

Comment: var currMonth = d.getMonth()+1;

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,
            format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
        });

$(".datepicker").datepicker('setDate', new Date());
    })
```

I used this it will worked. by aniksaha12

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

I changed code in line 1796 file 'bootstrap-datetimepicker.js'. It's worked for me

[image]