# Set current date in datepicker on page load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I will have a date picker on a form page using a datepicker (calendar bootstrap)

Now when you click on the click button, it opens and you can select a date.

But I need to have the current date instead of the click inscription when loading the page. How can I do that?

I need it to be exactly selected, as if we clicked on today's date. Because inside the calendar there will be another function that works when a date is selected

I tried installing `"setDate", new Date()` and other answers from this thread [bootstrap datepicker today as default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423467/bootstrap-datepicker-today-as-default), but nothing worked for me..

```js
let restaurantReserve = {
    init: function() {
        let _self = this;

        $('#reservation-date').datepicker({
            startDate: '+0d'
        }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
            const arDate = e.date.toString().split(' ');
            let input = $('[name="RestaurantReservationForm[date]"]');
            input.val(arDate[3] + '-' + (e.date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + arDate[2]);
            _self.unSetError(input);
            $('#reservation-date .js-value').text(arDate[2] + ' ' + arDate[1]);
        });
    },
    setError: function(ob) {
        $('#' + ob.data('btnId')).addClass('btn-error');
    },
    unSetError: function(ob) {
        $('#' + ob.data('btnId')).removeClass('btn-error');
    }
}

restaurantReserve.init();
```

```css
.btn {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-fourth {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #e3e5e8;
    color: #747b8b;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<a class="btn btn-fourth " id="reservation-date" data-date=">">
  <span class="icon br-calender"></span> <span class="js-value">click</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to get the current date in the same format as that of the datepicker.
- You can then set the current date of the datepicker to today's date (from above) once the datepicker has been initialized.

> Note: the value in `.datepicker('setValue', value)` must be of the same
> format as that of the datepicker `format` option. Eg. 26 Apr in your
> case

```js
let restaurantReserve = {
    init: function() {
        let _self = this;
        let today = new Date().toLocaleString('en-us',{day:'numeric', month:'short'}).split(' ').reverse().join(' '); // eg. Apr 26

        $('#reservation-date').datepicker({
            startDate: '+0d'
        }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
            const arDate = e.date.toString().split(' ');
            let input = $('[name="RestaurantReservationForm[date]"]');
            input.val(arDate[3] + '-' + (e.date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + arDate[2]);
            _self.unSetError(input);
            $('#reservation-date .js-value').text(arDate[2] + ' ' + arDate[1]);
        });

        $("#reservation-date").datepicker("setDate", today);
    },
    setError: function(ob) {
        $('#' + ob.data('btnId')).addClass('btn-error');
    },
    unSetError: function(ob) {
        $('#' + ob.data('btnId')).removeClass('btn-error');
    }
}

restaurantReserve.init();
```

```css
.btn {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-fourth {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #e3e5e8;
    color: #747b8b;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<a class="btn btn-fourth " id="reservation-date" data-date=">">
  <span class="icon br-calender"></span> <span class="js-value">click</span>
</a>
```